# bash grep search files by regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a files in my home directory named like database.2015-07-10.sql
I want to know amount of this files.

```
grep -l 'database' /home/user/* | wc -l
```

But when I try

```
grep -l 'database\.[0-9]{4}*' /home/user/*
```

or

```
grep -l 'database\.[0-9]*' /home/user/*
```

it gives no results, however

```
grep -l 'database\.[0-9]*' /home/user/*
```

gives all results including database12.sql, database1.sql etc
I don't understand regex in grep. Is it different somehow from regex in php?

Comment: What is your goal?  Do you want to search the contents of these files?  Or, do you want to counter the number of such files whose names match that pattern?

Comment: I wanna search names, not content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep searches for content, not for file names. You should use

```
ls /home/user/database*.sql|wc -l
```

or use

```
ls|grep 'YOUR PATTERN HERE'|wc -l
```

.

Comment: grep has a `-c` option for line count